# Javascript Float32 array throws Cannot read property '0' of null even though array is well defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, null

Here you can see the debug window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn0YA.png
As you can see, the array is NOT null and has in fact 2 elements. Why the hell am I getting that error ?

Edit: This code was written in C# and converted to JS via DuoCode:

```
WebGL.Vector2 = $d.declare("WebGL.Vector2", null, 62, $asm, function($t, $p) {
$t.cctor = function() {
    $t.GLVector2 = vec2;
};
$t.ctor = function Vector2() {
    this.vec = null;
};
$t.ctor.prototype = $p;
$p.get_X = function Vector2_get_X() {
    return this.vec[0]; //this is line 777
};
$p.set_X = function Vector2_set_X(value) {
    this.vec[0] = value;
    return value;
};
$p.get_Y = function Vector2_get_Y() {
    return this.vec[1];
};
$p.set_Y = function Vector2_set_Y(value) {
    this.vec[1] = value;
    return value;
};
$p.get_Magnitude = function Vector2_get_Magnitude() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.get_X() * this.get_X() + this.get_Y() * this.get_Y());
};
$p.get_Normalized = function Vector2_get_Normalized() {
    var m = this.get_Magnitude();
    return WebGL.Vector2.op_Division(this, m);
};
$t.ctor$1 = function Vector2() {
    this.vec = $d.array(System.Single, 2);
    this.set_X(0);
    this.set_Y(0);
};
$t.ctor$1.prototype = $p;
$t.ctor$2 = function Vector2(x, y) {
    this.vec = $d.array(System.Single, 2);
    this.set_X(x);
    this.set_Y(y);
};
$t.ctor$2.prototype = $p;
$p.Rotated = function Vector2_Rotated(angle) {
    var rad = Math.PI * angle / 180;
    var cs = Math.cos(rad);
    var sn = Math.sin(rad);
    return new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$2(this.get_X() * cs - this.get_Y() * sn, this.get_X() * sn + this.get_Y() * cs);
};
$p.Transformed = function Vector2_Transformed(matrix) {
    var ret = new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$1();
    $t().GLVector2.transformMat3(ret.vec, this.vec, matrix.mat);
    return ret;
};
$t.op_Multiply = function Vector2_op_Multiply(v, f) {
    return new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$2(v.get_X() * f, v.get_Y() * f);
};
$t.op_Division = function Vector2_op_Division(v, f) {
    return new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$2(v.get_X() / f, v.get_Y() / f);
};
$t.op_Addition = function Vector2_op_Addition(v1, v2) {
    return new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$2(v1.get_X() + v2.get_X(), v1.get_Y() + v2.get_Y());
};
$t.op_Subtraction = function Vector2_op_Subtraction(v1, v2) {
    return new WebGL.Vector2.ctor$2(v1.get_X() - v2.get_X(), v1.get_Y() - v2.get_Y());
};
$t.Dot = function Vector2_Dot(v1, v2) {
    return v1.get_X() * v2.get_X() + v1.get_Y() * v2.get_Y();
};
$p.ToString = function Vector2_ToString() {
    return String.Format("[{0}, {1}]", $d.array(System.Object, [this.get_X(), this.get_Y()]));
};
```

});

Comment: you shoud post some code

Comment: You didn't stop on the error but somewhen else, did you?

Comment: I stopped on line 777, exactly where the error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is a bad behavior, but it happens because of an experimental feature in C# 6 (parameterless constructors). Usually C# forbids declaring default constructors for structs, that's why there must be an automatic default ctor that initializes the struct (and sets null to reference-type fields like the array "vec").

C# 6 added the option for primary constructors - but Microsoft already realized that it's too complicated and I believe they plan to abandon this feature for now.

DuoCode uses Roslyn for compilation and that's the reason for this behavior. Next releases of Roslyn and DuoCode probably will forbid this.

I would recommend that you make your Vector2 struct as an immutable struct with two fields (x, y) - that would work the best.

Disclaimer: I work with the DuoCode developers

**Edit: Oops, it's called *parameterless constructors***

Comment: Ahh I see. Makes sense. The annoying thing is that structs in DuoCode must be immutable. Any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Okay the problem was the following: For some reason, DuoCode generates a default constructor for structs which initializes value types with null. My custom default constructor is ONLY called when I explicitly call Vector2 v = new Vector2(). This behavior is pretty unexpected and quite annoying to be honest. I hope this will be fixed in later releases.